# Find element where any attribute equals something

Tags: jquery, attributes

What I need is :

```
 jQuery("a[anyAttributeName='something']");
```

I do know how to do that with regular javascript...

Question:

Is there a way to do that just by using jQuery **selectors**?

For example:
You have elements a[**href**='value'], b[**title**='value'], c[**src**='value'].

I want by using 1 jQuery selector find elements where any of attributes has value...

I don't wanna do something like that
                $("a[href='value'], b[title='value'], c[scr='value']") 
because I have 1k elements.

Comment: what is the question? I think you have the answer as you have written

Comment: What do you mean by "jQuery selectors?" I would describe what you have as a jQuery selector (or more likely, a CSS selector). What do you mean by "regular JavaScript?" Do you want to use DOM methods directly, rather than via jQuery?

Comment: @JustinMorgan http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors

Comment: @ShovanSahu the question is "Is there a way to do that just by using jQuery selectors?"

Comment: You had already written jquery selector. you can remove a from that to match any tag. Check my answer

Comment: I know what a jQuery selector is. What you have written, `"a[anyAttributeName='something']"`, is a jQuery selector. Or rather, it is a string of them. Please make it clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use filter to do what you want:

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    for(var i = 0, l = this.attributes.length; i < l; i++)
        if(this.attributes[i].nodeValue === 'something')
            return this;
});
```

To use it as a selector, you need to create it yourself :

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], { 
    value: function(a, _, v) { 
        for(var i = 0, l = a.attributes.length; i < l; i++)
            if(a.attributes[i].nodeValue === v[3])
                return true;
        return false;
    }
})
```

Then use it like that :

```
$('div:value(test)');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/55BZ3/

Comment: Almost but nope.

I need search by attribute value.

Comment: @nazarkin659 i see what you want (i think). see my edit.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same, now I am thinking is there a way to do that inside of selector...

Comment: @nazarkin659 no, but you can add a custom selector, see my futur edit.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Have question about your code:  why v[3] ?

Comment: @nazarkin659 great question! Can't tell you why exactly, but if you check what contain `v`, it is an array and the value you need is in the cell 3.

Comment: Actually, here the answer : http://jquery-howto.blogspot.ca/2009/06/jquery-custom-selectors-with-parameters.html

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. It's makes a little bit clear for me =)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would use something like this:

```
$("a[href='foo']");
```

[Source](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Using the `jQuery` keyword instead of `$()` is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is

```
$("[anyAttributeName='something']")
```